# django 'LIKE' statement in Model.objects.raw()

Tags: mysql, django, sql-like

I have problem in django using query statement "like %s%" with Model.objects.raw(). I guess the problem is on '%' character but i don't know where is it. Here's my model's code:

```
def listInRange(self, placeLat, placeLng, typeId, range, placeTag):
    tags = ''
    if placeTag:
        tags = "AND (placeTag LIKE '%" + "%' OR placeTag LIKE '%".join(placeTag.split(',')) + "%')"

    query = "SELECT *, \
            ( \
                6371000 * \
                acos( \
                    cos( radians(%s) ) * \
                    cos( radians(placeLat) ) * \
                    cos( radians(placeLng) - radians(%s) ) + \
                    sin( radians(%s) ) * \
                    sin( radians(placeLat) ) \
                ) \
            ) AS placeDistance, \
        COUNT(r.reviewId) as placeReviews, \
        (SUM(r.reviewPointPrice)/COUNT(r.reviewId)+SUM(r.reviewPointService)/COUNT(r.reviewId)+SUM(r.reviewPointLocation)/COUNT(r.reviewId)+SUM(r.reviewPointCondition)/COUNT(r.reviewId)+SUM(r.reviewPointComfort)/COUNT(r.reviewId))/5 AS averagePoint \
        FROM place_place p \
        LEFT JOIN review_review r \
        ON r.reviewPlace_id = p.placeId\
        WHERE placeType_id = %s %s \
        GROUP BY p.placeId \
        HAVING placeDistance < %s \
        ORDER BY placeDistance"

    return Place.objects.raw(query, [placeLat, placeLng, placeLat, typeId, tags, range])
```

If placeTag is not empty, then it will added to the WHERE condition. When the placeTag is empty there's no such problem, but when placeTag is not empty i got this error :

```
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1AND (placeTag LIKE '%cafe%' OR placeTag LIKE '%pub%')'
```

What's the better way to write the sql statement using Model.objects.raw() with 'like' statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"1AND"` in the output first makes me think you're missing some space characters (at the beginning and end of the string used to join for ex).

In your case, your where clause is `"WHERE placeType_id = 1AND (placeTag..."`

---

Usualy that kind of error is raised if you try to compare a double to something that is not, but it's also often raised when logical assertions are not spelled right.

Later, if you have errors "column doesn't exist", be careful with the caps, some DBGS do not read case out of "" or ''.

Comment: i've changed it to : "WHERE placeType_id=%s %s \" and got error : "Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1 AND (placeTag LIKE '%tes%')'". what now?

Comment: I guess python make '1 AND (placeTag LIKE '%tes%')' as the value for placeType_id. How can i make the value of placeType_id=1 and add the AND statement?